Option pricing via fourier transform

can someone help me understand the steps from (1) to the following row? where does the 1/2 comes from, after I apply the fourier transform to the probability density and swithch the integral order I cannot go on.

Gil-Pelaez' (1951) Fourier inversion formula states that for any probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{e^{-i\ln(K)u}\phi_{\ln(S_T)}^\mathbb{Q}(u)}{iu}\right)\mathrm{d}u = \pi\left(\mathbb{Q}\big[\{S_T\geq K\}\big] - \frac{1}{2}\right).
\end{align}
Here, $\phi_{\ln(S_T)}^\mathbb{Q}(u)=\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[e^{iu\ln(S_T)}]$ is the characteristic function of the log process $\ln(S_T)$. $\text{Re}$ is the real part of a complex number.
Indeed, many Fourier methods in finance boil down to this (or a similar) inversion formula. It directly links exercise probabilities to improper integrals of characteristic functions (Fourier transformations of probability density functions).
